# How to affect other elements if SVG is hovered over?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this issue here where I have an `svg` as a logo next to my `.brand-name` class. What I have done so far is to make sure the `svg` looks like it's a part of the `.brand-name` class, meaning that whenever I hover over the `.brand-name` class, the `svg` also appears as if it was hovered over. However, I could not find any material as to how to get the opposite effect; meaning that when I hover over the `svg`, the `.brand-name` class also appears like it's been hovered over. I have been researching this topic using [this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered) but I couldn't come up with a solution that could fit the `svg` to `.brand-name` class issue.

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="brand">
    <li><a href="#" class="logo-container">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="40px" height="35px" viewBox="0 0 363.818 363.818" style="enable-background:new 0 0 363.818 363.818;" xml:space="preserve">
        <path class="logo" d="M358.872,0.841c-3.196-1.538-7.014-0.931-9.572,1.526c-19.515,18.728-53.141,46.415-102.511,71.961    c-2.159,1.118-3.737,3.106-4.333,5.463c-4.028,15.908-11.933,33.271-23.492,51.607l-4.705,7.462l8.772-38.205    c0.715-3.115-0.378-6.368-2.828-8.42c-2.451-2.052-5.846-2.556-8.786-1.303l-1.015,0.428    C110.79,133.291,81.352,198.24,72.67,233.22c-3.013,12.141-4.516,24.163-4.465,35.738c0.02,4.466,0.272,8.722,0.75,12.705    l-66.39,67.703c-3.211,3.273-3.246,8.505-0.078,11.822c1.667,1.745,3.904,2.629,6.149,2.629c2.02,0,4.045-0.717,5.664-2.164    l182.428-163.851c0.896,0.059-103.874,109.806-102.925,109.806c14.22,0,33.863-6.555,56.804-18.95    c30.935-16.717,65.508-42.37,99.979-74.185c2.832-2.612,3.551-6.805,1.753-10.213c-1.798-3.407-5.662-5.181-9.42-4.315    l-21.363,4.904l7.465-4.706c20.835-13.136,40.313-21.511,57.891-24.897c1.901-0.367,3.622-1.372,4.875-2.849    c41.348-48.75,58.853-96.919,66.256-128.743c2.69-11.567,4.579-23.134,5.607-34.38C363.972,5.742,362.069,2.379,358.872,0.841z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
      </svg>
    </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="brand-name">Company Name</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.header ul.brand .logo {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out fill;
}
.header ul.brand:hover .logo {
  fill: #fbabab;
  color: #fbabab;
}
.header ul.brand .logo:hover {
  fill: #fbabab;
  color: #fbabab;
}
```

I've already created the motion where the `svg` appears to be hovered over when the user hovers over the `.brand-name` anchor class.

Additionally, **if more information is required to aid me on this issue, I'd be more than grateful to help out to provide such. Please comment down below if such clarification is necessary.** Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add hover to both at the same time:

```
.header ul.brand:hover .logo,
.header ul.brand:hover .brand-name {
  fill: #fbabab;
  color: #fbabab;
}
```

Or

```
.header ul.brand:hover .logo {
  fill: #fbabab;
}
.header ul.brand:hover .brand-name {
  color: #fbabab;
}
```

---

However, I would simplify the HTML to:

```
<header>
  <a href="#">
    <svg>...</svg>
    <span>Company Name</span>
  </a>
</header>
```

And use this as an example:

```
header a:hover svg {
  ...
}
header a:hover span {
  ...
}
```